# Torch.cuda.is_available() is false for cuda 11.8

Tags: python, pytorch

I have been struggling with this problem for the last two days yet not resolved.
My torch.cuda.is_available() is always False despite whatever I try. But there is no problem with Tensorflow for the GPU.

My Details:
Cuda Version: 11.8
Cudnn: available for cuda 11.x
python version: 3.10.4
Visual Studio: 2022
OS: Windows 10

Installation Method Used For Pytorch:
Used as mentioned in Pytorch: https://pytorch.org/

Command:
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117

Please please please help

Comment: Pytorch just doesn't support CUDA 11.8 yet, I think. You will need to downgrade to CUDA 11.7 or wait.

Answer (score 0):

From the official site [torch](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/). There is no Cuda 11.8 support yet started. So try `11.7` or `11.6`